# How to find white space between specific words in python

Tags: python

I am trying to find the space count between the specific word and its adjacent word.

I have following string:

```
"${test}=    Test word      browser      mozilla"
```

Now I am trying to get count of white spaces between word `Test word` and `browser`. This word are changes per lines.

Note - There are multiple white spaces between these two words.

Comment: My advice is to have a look at regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this?

```
>>> import re
>>> string = "${test}=    Test word      browser      mozilla"
>>> re.search('Test word( +)browser', string).group(1)
'      '
>>> len(re.search('Test word( +)browser', string).group(1))
6
>>>
```

Or without regex:

```
>>> string = "${test}=    Test word      browser      mozilla"
>>> string.split('Test word')[1].split('browser')[0]
'      '
>>> len(string.split('Test word')[1].split('browser')[0])
6
>>>
```

Comment: This requires that the adjacent word be know. I'm not sure that it is.

Comment: @mhawke: Hmm...OP said that *Now I am trying to get count of white spaces between word `Test word` and `browser`.*

Comment: @mhawke: Actually if we don't know what's the adjacent word, it can be done via RegEx: `len(re.search('Test word( +)\w', string).group(1))` or use `str.split()` get the adjacent word first.

Comment: Yep, already have a regex solution in my answer that does not require knowing the following word. It also handles whitespace characters other then space, e.g. tabs, newline, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using a regular expression:

```
import re

s = '${test}= Test word browser mozilla'
target = 'Test word'
pattern = r'{}(\s+)'.format(target)
count = len(re.findall(pattern, s)[0])
```

This regex pattern will locate the target word(s) in the string and match on any sequence of whitespace characters that follows it.

An alternative is to use [`string.partition()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) to split the string on the target word(s) and then process the results of that:

```
import string

s = '${test}= Test word browser mozilla'
target = 'Test word'
head, sep, tail = s.partition(target)
if tail:
    count = 0
    for c in tail:
        if c in string.whitespace:
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    print(count)
else:
    print("Target word(s) {} not present".format(target))
```